# Ordinal logistic regression: sensitivity / specifity

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, sensitivity-specificity

I am trying to determine the sensitivity and specificity per category of an outcome with ordinal categories between 1 and 6 predicted by 5 predictors.

Overall accuracy is around 45%, but I want to see which categories are predicted better than others.

Is this making any sense? 
If yes, can someone give me a hint how to do this (e.g. R package)?

**Overall accuracy:**

```
predictCriterion <- predict(OLRmodel,df)
table(df$Criterion, predictCriterion)  

predictCriterion
     1  2  3  4  5  6
  1  0  1  0  0  3  0
  2  0  0  0  4  8  0
  3  0  0  0  3 12  1
  4  0  1  0  2 37  2
  5  0  0  0  2 88 11
  6  0  0  0  0 43 14

mean(as.character(df$Criterion) != as.character(predictCriterion))
```

`[1] 0.5517241`

Comment: you are predicting almost everything to be 5, you can see this with table(predictCriterion)

Comment: So most likely you need to fix that first before going down to finding out which classes are predicted better

Comment: @StupidWolf, any suggestions how to "fix" this?

Comment: Addition: categories 1-2-3 are underrepresented

Comment: Hi @Jens.. yes good point. You can increase the weights of the other classes for example. Or from the model, do you have an idea if any variable is driving the prediction to be 5?